# serialize a form in groups

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to serialize a form in separate groups?

```
<form id="form">
    <input class="nameF" type="text" name="fName" value="first name">
    <input class="nameF" type="text" name="lName" value="last name">
    <input class="address" type="text" name="addOne" value="home address">
    <input class="address" type="text" name="zip" value="zip code">
    <input class="address" type="text" name="country" value="country">
</form>

$('#form').serialize();

//this gives me the complete form serialized
```

but can I break it down in groups with the fields containing class name?

Something like `nameF : first+name&last+name` and same for address, is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like :

```
console.log($('.nameF').serialize());
console.log($('.address').serialize());
```

If you didn't get your answer , elaborate your question with full example.

Comment: @bhanushankar--I got what I was looking for. Sometimes its easy not to be very specific..then you can understand the principal than finding an immediate solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form">
    <input class="nameF" type="text" name="fName" value="first name"/>
        <input class="nameF" type="text" name="lName" value="last name"/>
        <input class="address" type="text" name="address[addOne]" value="home address"/>
        <input class="address" type="text" name="address[zip]" value="zip code"/>
        <input class="address" type="text" name="address[country]" value="country"/>
</form>
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5JC7V/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

You can use -

```
$('input .nameF').serialize();
$('input .address').serialize();
```

You can test it using-

```
alert(JSON.stringify($('input .nameF').serialize()));
```

Comment: @vinay--is that a jquery native function?

Comment: -1 there is no method `serializeObject` in jQuery API